# Size on Disk of multiple tiny files

Tags: c#, windows, hard-drive, diskspace

> Size: ~5mb
>
> Size on Disk: ~3gb

We're using C# and saving data constantly as it changes, all of the file data has to be accessible at any given time. Basically if something changes the file for that data must save. This is why there are so many files for so much data. The data is processed greatly as well so clumping all of it together is not an option as a minor change would result in a large amount being saved for no reason. These files already contain enough that saving one is mostly redundant for only a small change.

Surely there is a way to get around this absurd expansion of the file size, and still retain the accessibility and  saving-efficiency we have achieved. We need a way to package these files into what windows will consider to be a single file, but in such a way that we do not have to rewrite the entire file when something changes.

I understand that having thousands of small files is quite strange, but for our purposes it has improved performance greatly. We just don't want to sacrifice one resource for another if it is at all possible to avoid.

Note: The files have RLE binary data, they are not text files.

Clarity update: 5mb->3gb = 250mb (50x clusters) -> 150gb = PROBLEM!

Comment: So you're basically keeping versions of the files? Do you know when a "small file" is no longer needed?

Comment: Is 3GB a problem? What's your projected typical/high possible usage? Hard-disk space is _cheap_. Beyond that, possible to move the data to a database? If this current implementation of yours is based on a measurable performance need (as you mentioned), I'm assuming you've tried other obvious methods (like one large file as you suggested, or a database) and determined they're not sufficient?

Comment: My guess: those files are on a huge volume that uses a large allocation unit size. If you plan to continue using lots of tiny files, specifically format the volume with the minimum possible allocation unit. For NTFS that's 4Kb.

Comment: Engineering is, almost by definition, the tradeoff of competing technical requirements. In today's world 3GB is rather a small disk space requirement, where 1TB disks are quite reasonably purchased.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A database does exactly what you need: You can store arbitrary amounts of tiny rows/blobs and they will be stored efficiently. File systems typically require at least one disk cluster per file which is probably why your size expands so much. Databases don't do that. You can also ask the database to compact itself.

There are embedded and standalone databases available.

Comment: In this particular case we will be storing, fetching, modifying, and deleting blob file representations at a rate of about 200 a second. I didn't think a database would be a viable option for something  of that nature. Am I incorrect in that assumption ? The files in question range from about 500b to 2kb.

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect because RDBMS performance varies with usage patterns. In all cases that I can think of it will be faster than the file system for your particular use case (lots of tiny blobs only accessed by primary key).

Comment: Cool. I've been looking around a bit since your comment and I'm think of checking out RavenDB as a possible solution now. Do you have an alternative database that you would recommend I look into?

Comment: I'd rather pick one of the most common ones which are also faster: SQLite, Firebird, BerkeleyDB (in that order). RavenDB is not made for what you want. You need one of the old, traditional RDBMS'es.

Comment: Ok I'll check into those then. Thanks for the help. I'll mark this as the answer once I get something working and test the efficiency out.